# Multiple log files for AutoTouch

Tags: logging, lua, autotouch

I'm trying to make my AutoTouch app log events in a separate file for each script.  For example, I'd like script1.lua to log events in script1.log.

I've tried the following:

```
--code here
log(/var/mobile/Library/AutoTouch//Library/script1.log and "Log Message Here")
--code here
```

Next I tried:

```
--code here
log(script1.log("Log message here"))
--code here
```

The final code I tried was:

```
--code here
log(/script1.log("Log Message Here"))
```

On all of these code blocks, I receive the error alert:

```
Unexpected symbol near '/'
```

Have I made a syntax error somewhere, or does this feature not exist?

Answer (score 1):

All [Lua strings](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) need to be put in matching delimiters (single or double quotes; there are also long strings in square brackets) and this is why you get the errors.

As to the log location, I don't see any way in [AutoTouch log documentation](http://autotouch.me/?page_id=5#log) to change the location of the log file.